# Как сгенерировать код в Qt Designer (PyQt)?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

Как сгенерировать код в Qt Designer (PyQt)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

сохраняй в например example.ui  и в командной строке(cmd) командой "pyuic4 example.ui -o example.py"  превращай в код )

Answer (score 0):

читайте в доках про uic.exe