# DLL load failed: %1 не является приложением Win32

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

В IDLE при запуске PyQt кода выдает ошибку

> DLL load failed: %1 не является приложением Win32

Стоит PyQt5 x32. Если поставлю 64 то будет писать что модуль не найден.

Процессор и винда х64.

Если попытаться преобразовать проект из Qt Designer в питоновский код через командную строку (как было сказано [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/30264/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2-qt-designer-pyqt)) то увидим ту же ошибку.

Comment: А у Python какая разрядность? Как PyQT  устанавливали?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Python х32. PyQt нашел exe-шный файл на 32 бита и установил в папку с питоном

Comment: Установите 64-битный Python и прекомпилированный для x64 PyQt [отсюда](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev `C:\Users\User>pip install PyQt4-4.11.4-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

Requirement 'PyQt4-4.11.4-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist

PyQt4-4.11.4-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Comment: Сообщение "...is not a supported wheel on this platform" означает, что либо Python не x64, либо не 3.6, а может и то, и другое вместе.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev я установил Python 3.6 x64 с оф. сайта

Comment: @JohnyJay откройте этот питон и введите эту команду `import platform; print(platform.platform())` И скажите что она выведет + приглашение от питона

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите этот [ответ на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33868351), таже проблема, что и у вас.

Тут может быть только одно решение - разрядность интерпритатора и всех установленных модулей должна совпадать.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/531478)

Comment: Страница по ссылке ведет на SO, она не может стать недействительной. Основная мысль из ответа по ссылке приведено одним предложением. Разве вы этого не видите? Предложите, что еще оттуда можно добавить.

Comment: Дело в том, что ответы ссылки ответами не являются ни в каком случае. Тем более, что ссылка _может_ стать недействительной.

Comment: Я вам выше все написал, вы наверное невнимательно прочли. Это не ответ-ссылка, т.к. основное из ответа по ссылке я указал в своём ответе. Ссылка на ответ в предалах сайта SO может стать недействительной только в одном случае, если SO закроeтся, обанкротится, например. Так что ответ короткий и правильный. Если у вас есть желание перенести остальное "бла-бла" из ответа по ссылке, или можете предложить другое решение (что сомнительно), то дайте свой ответ. А если нет, то поставте лайк, чтобы я хоть комментировать мог.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Вот даже нашёл вам [в справке насчёт ссылок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Заметьте, упомянуты: _Ссылки на внешние ресурсы._., а сайт SO это внутренний ресурс.

Comment: Нет, вы не правы, ссылка на enSO, а у нас _ru.SO_.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Ну раз вы так считаете, ладно. Но я уже три раза написал - причина ошибки стоит в моем ответе. Что вы можете предложить к ней добавить?