# Невозможно преобразовать Qt Designer .ui в .ру

Tags: python, windows, qt, pyqt5

не могу преобразовать проект в python код, выдает ошибку

PyQt5 x64 и Python 3.6 x64 установлены, Windows 10 x64

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И возможно это как-то связанно с [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610280/dll-load-failed-1-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-win32?noredirect=1#comment836966_610280)

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно использовать `pyuic5.bat` из директории *PyQt5*

Посмотри следующее: [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429452/convert-pyqt-ui-to-python) и [тут](http://1.pyqtforlinguists.appspot.com/ebook/_2____pyqt5.html).

Comment: Я перешел по второй ссылке и следовал тому что было сказано там. В итоге командная строка сказала мне "ImportError: Module use of python35.dll conflicts with this version of Python."
Переустановить питон на 3.5?!

Comment: Вероятно...
На Python 3.6 пока мало того, что есть.
К тому-же, для начала нужно дождаться обновления PyQt

Answer (score 0):

PyQt5 с  Python 3.6 не работает поставь 3.5

Comment: Дайте более развёрнутый ответ - почему не работает?